# Testing components using jest that includes canvas

Tags: canvas, jestjs, enzyme, zoomcharts

I'm trying to test `zoomcharts` component in my `react` app with `Enzyme` and `jest`. There is a reference error relevant to canvas.
Here is my test case:

```
import Chart from './Shared/Chart';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('test 1',()=>{
    it('Chart',()=>{
        let wrapper = shallow(<Chart/>);
    });
});
```

and here is my error when I run my test:

```
ReferenceError: CanvasGradient is not defined

  28 |             ]
  29 |         };
> 30 |         this.chart = new zc.NetChart({
     |                      ^
  31 |             container: this.container, 
  32 |             area: { height: 350 },
  33 |             data: { preloaded: data }
```

Is there any problem with testing components that includes canvas element?
How can I mock this `CanvasGradient` thing? I've already tried `jest-canvas-mock`. Thanks.

Comment: I've made a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984083/charts-created-using-react-chartjs-2-throw-an-error-in-a-jest-environment). No solution yet.